# It is possible to find $x$ rows and $y$ columns to intersect between which are squares containing the number $1$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

On a table $n$ x $n $ , we fill in the squares of the table with the number $0$ or $1$. Know that if you select any $n$ cells such that no two cells are in the same row or column, then they contain at least one number $1$. Prove that there is a positive integer $x,y$ such that $x +y >n$, such that it is possible to find $x$ rows and $y$ columns to intersect between which are squares containing the number $1$.

My idea is to consider a bipartite graph $G=(A,B)$ where $A$ is the set of rows , $B$ is the set of columns , $2$ vertices $u,v$ join if cells square with coordinates $(u,v)$ contains the number $1$.
Then we brought the problem to graph theory , but I have no idea what to do further . Looking forward to getting help from everyone. Thanks very much !

Comment: Use Hall’s marriage theorem, where zero means “willing to marry”. Since every bijective  assignment of rows to columns contains at least one “1”, no marriage is possible, so the Hall condition must fail…

Comment: The $n$ cells whose position $(x,y)$ is such that $x+y=n+1$ are on different rows and or different columns. On at least one of them, there is the number $1$.